# Are scoped static variables shared between threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

E.g., can the following code ever print "3" for one of the threads?

```
int foo()
{
   static int a = 1;
   return ++a;
}

void thread1()
{
   cout<<foo()<<endl;
}

void thread2()
{
   cout<<foo()<<endl;
}
```

edit: It's C++ 98

Comment: Because even if they're shared, race conditions might cause it to print "2" every time for both threads, so I might be mislead.

Comment: No, how should that be possible. It will always print `2`. And there is no race-condition, because the initialization of `a` is automatically synchronized.

Comment: @nosid because of this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/08/85901.aspx , but it seems to be from 2004 so I'm not sure.

Comment: @nosid: It is? Automatically synchronized by which mechanism?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: It's intractible to prove behaviours of multi-threaded programs through experimentation alone. It requires analysis.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit The 01 update to the 99 standard?

Comment: @TravisG: Neither such standard exists... There is C++98, C++03 and C++11.

Comment: 98 then? :D 4 more to go

Comment: It is rather pointless asking about threads in versions of C++ prior to C++11, because they simply did not exist (as far as the standard and the language was concerned).

Comment: @Mankarse Just out of interest, how is it in C++ 11?

Comment: @Mankarse I mean... are local static variables shared between threads in C++11?

Comment: @Mankarse: It is the opposite of pointless to point out that -- for the reason you bring up -- this functionality is _not_ thread-safe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course it can print 3. It is even the "usual semantics" of this code to do so. Thread 1 initializes it with 1 and increments it, so it is 2. Thread 2 increments it again, so it is 3.

So, yes, scoped static variables are **static**, i.e., global variables. They are shared by threads.

Of course, the code has a race condition, so the result can possibly be anything, but 3 is a possible result.

Comment: The code has undefined behaviour (due to the race condition in `++a`), so there are no "usual semantics".

Comment: still, you will get 3 on most compilers in most situations. But you are right, "usual semantics" is a quite strange word which is not defined anyway, so I placed it in quotes now... Btw: In C++11, the semantics of a program with race conditions is not fully undefined.

Comment: Race conditions are definitely fully undefined -- see `[intro.multithread]/21`: `The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in dierent threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.`

Answer (score 3):

local static variables are shared between threads.

Initialisation of function-local static variables is thread-safe in C++11 (before that, threads did not even exist ;)).

Modification of function-local static variables, on the other hand, is not thread-safe, so your modified code has undefined behaviour (due to the race condition).

Comment: So they're not shared? If I let one thread wait a second and let the other execute first, the waiting thread will still print 2?

Comment: The key here is "C++11". Is the OP using C++11? He didn't mention it. I think we're still at the point where somebody says if they're using C++11, as most people and most production environments are not. And then this initialisation is absolutely _not_ thread-safe.

Comment: @TravisG *"So they're not shared?"* - No, they **are** shared. It's only the initialization that is thread-safe (I don't know this, but I believe *Mankarse* here), so you won't have two threads trying to initialize the variable. The variable itself **is** shared and even if you synchronize the access, you still have one thread printing 2 and the other 3. And without synchronization it's UB, anyway, as said in the answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, good compilers have had thread-safe init of statics for years, long before C++11 - you can't say "absolutely" whether the init is safe

Comment: @JonathanWakely: GCC, yes. VS as of 2009, no. Perhaps it does now. In C++ itself? Absolutely not. Writing code for anything other than a specific version of a specific toolchain on a specific platform? Don't rely on it. [Citation for this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1962918/560648)

Comment: @ChristianRau: The initialisation is thread-safe **only in C++11**, which the OP is _not_ using. For C++98, it is only "_possibly_ thread-safe in practice" which is a very different thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, GCC is the default compiler on more than "a specific platform" and the OP doesn't say which platform(s) are being used, and it doesn't apply only to specific versions of GCC, or even to specific toolchains - Clang supports it too. As I said, good compilers support it, if yours doesn't then change it. But you cannot say "absolutely" one way or the other. Lots of people have been able to rely on thread-safe init of local statics for years, so your comment is not "absolutely" accurate.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: In the real world, you can't just "change it" because your code relies on thread-safe function-static initialisation instead of using the appropriate locks suggested by the lack of an implementation guarantee. In the real world, your choice of toolchain comes down to many, many more factors than that and switching toolchains potentially has significant consequences elsewhere. Lots of people have been able to rely on thread-safe init if, like I said, they know for a fact that their version of GCC makes it safe -- I suspect many only _think_ that they can rely on it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *"The initialisation is thread-safe only in C++11"* - Yes, I said nothing contrary and relied on the fact that *Mankarse* **already clearly stated that** in his answer, disregarding of the fact if it is what the OP uses. But you're right in that it doesn't help the OP much and I also understand (and support) your sentiments against relying on the correct implementation-defined behaviour of one certain compiler (which may be the most widely used, but still is not the only one, and VC is definitely not a niche compiler either).