# ERROR - more than one operator == matches these operands

Tags: c++, thread-safety, singleton

I'm trying to make a "thread-safe", singleton, but I'm getting this stupid error:

Class Header:

```
class Engine
{
public:
    static Engine* Instance(void);
private:
    Engine() {}
    static std::atomic<Engine*> pinstance;
    static std::mutex m_;
```

Class Source:

```
std::atomic<Engine*> Engine::pinstace { nullptr };
std::mutex Engine::_m;

Engine* Engine::Instance()
{
    if (pinstance == nullptr) {
    //            ^^ I get error here
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_);
    if (pinstance == nullptr) {
    //            ^^ I get error also here
        pinstance = new Engine();
    }
    }
    return pinstance;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: If you're using C++ 11, there are much easier ways to create thread-safe singletons.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11  In other words, you're doing all the work that the C++ 11 standard now guarantees must be done for static variables.

Comment: So you think that using visual studio 2013, and doing:

`Engine& Engine::Singleton()
{
 static Engine instance;
 return instance;
}` will work?

Comment: Yes, that is all you need to do, but not with Visual Studio 2013.  See the link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096970/when-is-a-divide-by-zero-not-a-divide-by-zero-a-puzzle-in-the-debugger-static/28098631#28098631  You need to use Visual Studio 2015, as that version correctly implements the static initialization.