# c++ function pointer assignment is safe?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Is this code thread safe?

```
static PFN_SOMEFUNC pfnSomeFunc = nullptr;

PFN_SOMEFUNC SomeFuncGetter();

void CalledFromManyThreads() {
    if (pfnSomeFunc == nullptr)
        pfnSomeFunc = SomeFuncGetter();

    pfnSomeFunc();
}
```

This is not atomic pointer operation question. There are some special conditions.

- SomeFuncGetter() always returns same address.
- SomeFuncGetter() is thread safe.

Comment: It's not. Wrap `pfunSomeFunc` with `std::atomic`.

Comment: You can make it a static *local* variable and benefit from [this awesome quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8102145/8584929) in the C++ standard.

Comment: There is no synchronization used in the code, so there is no thread-safety in the code you posted.  What happens outside this code -- this is the only code you posted and asked a question about.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie pfnSomeFunc is modified by CalledFromManyThreads() function. And pfnSomeFunc can have only one value. Can there be a synchronization problem?

Comment: It is not thread-safe.  `pfnSomeFunc = SomeFuncGetter();` The `=` is not thread-safe in itself.  Maybe, just maybe 30 years ago, the code was "thread-safe" in the sense that processors were less sophisticated.  But in this day and age, comparison and assignment (plus using mere `boolean` flags) is not going to get you thread-safety.  Only the use of proper synchronization is going to give you those results.

Comment: @chaeyk   Yes, there is a "synchronization problem".    Your assertion that `pfSomeFunc` can only have one value is incorrect - the code specifies two values (`nullptr` on initialisation, the value returned by `SomeFuncGetter()` on a subsequent assignment).   Since there is no synchronisation in this code, race conditions exist affecting both the comparison of `pfSomeFunc` with `nullptr` and the assignment - either (or both) of those operations may be pre-empted (since neither operation is atomic) by another thread when partially complete.

Comment: @Peter -- A couple years ago, I worked for a company where the head programmer  from the 1980's couldn't wrap their head around the fact that you couldn't achieve thread-safety by  doing a comparison and setting a couple of `bool` variables.   Frustrating to say the least.

Comment: @Peter Good! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look thread-safe, because the global variable can be modified by any thread without synchronization.  Even an assignment is not guaranteed to be atomic.

What you *could* do is leverage a language feature that guarantees thread-safe atomic initialization by moving the static into your function (a very common solution to the Static Initialization Fiasco):

```
void CalledFromManyThreads() {
    static PFN_SOMEFUNC pfnSomeFunc = SomeFuncGetter();
    pfnSomeFunc();
}
```

Now it's thread-safe.  And if you need that cached result in multiple places, you can wrap it:

```
PFN_SOMEFUNC GetSomeFunc()
{
    static PFN_SOMEFUNC pfnSomeFunc = SomeFuncGetter();
    return pfnSomeFunc;
}

void CalledFromManyThreads() {
    PFN_SOMEFUNC pfnSomeFunc = GetSomeFunc();
    pfnSomeFunc();
}
```

Comment: It's true it's thread safe as per the C++11 standard.  It wasn't thread-safe for earlier than C++11.

Comment: With visual studio 2010, some threads get null value from static pfnSomeFunc.

Comment: VS 2010 does not support C++11

Comment: @chaeyk -- You need to be on Visual Studio 2015, SP 3 or later to see the full effects of what paddy is showing you.  Earlier versions of Visual Studio lacked this feature.  [See this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096970/when-is-a-divide-by-zero-not-a-divide-by-zero-a-puzzle-in-the-debugger-static) concerning "magic statics" and the support for them in Visual Studio.

Comment: @chaeyk -- Also, I would recommend not using VS 2010 for development if you really want to use C++11.   The compiler has several C++11 "features" that are actually broken  (like brace initialization rules and lambdas) -- so if you use any C++11 idioms using that compiler, you're risking things.