# Are pre-main global initializers guaranteed to run single-threaded?

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer

For example, the `node::node()` constructor in the following snippet accesses the globals `node::count` and `::tail` without any multithread guards. Does the C++ standard guarantee that the output would always be a permutation of `0 1 2` (regardless of the order)?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node *tail;

struct node
{
    static int count;

    int index;
    node *prev;

    node()
    {   index = count++; prev = tail; tail = this; }
};

int node::count;

node one, two[2];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(node *p = tail; p; p = p->prev)
        printf("%d\n", p->index);

    return 0;
}
```

I am looking for an answer based on the (applicable) standard, not for implementation or compiler specific behaviors. There are a number of related questions on SO but it's not entirely clear how they directly apply to this particular and rather basic case ([Is C++ static member variable initialization thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962880/is-c-static-member-variable-initialization-thread-safe), [Is local static variable initialization thread-safe in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11) etc).

Comment: Which C++ standard? Did you check this http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm Dynamic Initialization and Destruction with Concurrency, Non-Local Initialization and  [basic.start.init] of 14 - http://cpp14.centaur.ath.cx/basic.start.init.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211237/static-variables-initialisation-order would be helpful!

Comment: @osgx `Which C++ standard?` I would be interested to find out if the answer changed between the standards. Thank you for the pointers.

Comment: @YogiJoshi Thanks, but that's about the *order* of initialization, while I specifically asked about the thread-safety of the initializers (per the `regardless of the order` part of my question).

Comment: Related: [static global variables initialization order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54159044) puts some guarantees on the order of static initialization within a TU.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the pointer. If I read that right, the globals in my snippet count as "*ordered*", which would guarantee both safe initialization, and an output of `2,1,0`. That's consistent with Igor's answer from years ago, but spelled out more explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initialization of global variables is guaranteed single-threaded as long as the program doesn't itself start a thread (e.g. in a constructor of some global variable); once that happens, the implementation is then allowed to parallellize remaining initializations, to some extent.

> **[basic.start.init]/2** ...Variables with ordered initialization defined within a single translation unit shall be initialized in the order of their definitions in the translation unit. If a program starts a thread (30.3), the subsequent initialization of a variable is unsequenced with respect to the initialization of a variable defined in a different translation unit. Otherwise, the initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the initialization of a variable defined in a different translation unit. If a program starts a thread, the subsequent unordered initialization of a variable is unsequenced with respect to every other dynamic initialization. Otherwise, the unordered initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with respect to every other dynamic initialization. [ *Note:* This definition permits initialization of a sequence of ordered variables concurrently
>   with another sequence. *—end note* ]

"Indeterminately sequenced" is the part that guarantees single-threaded execution. By definition, the notion of *sequenced {before, after, indeterminately}* is only meaningful within a single thread:

> **[intro.execution]/13** *Sequenced before* is a ... relation between evaluations executed by a single thread...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It is meaningless to say that an evaluation on one thread is "sequenced" with an evaluation on a different thread. One could happen before/after the other, but it cannot be sequenced before/after/indeterminately with the other. "**[intro.execution]/13** *Sequenced before* is a ... relation between evaluations executed by a single thread..."

Comment: The `within a single translation` part is only incidental to the MCVE I posted, of course. And the language is rather confusing. `Otherwise, the initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the initialization of a variable defined in a different translation unit.` I take this to mean that, assuming no other threads were deliberately launched, even if I moved `node two[2];` to a different .cpp, it would still be `sequenced` with respect to `node one;` - only `indeterminately` so (i.e. order not guaranteed), as opposed to `unsequenced` (i.e. potentially multithread).