# static global variables initialization order

Tags: c++, initialization, global-variables, language-lawyer, operator-precedence

In many of the answers that I found here were said the following words:

> Global variables in a single translation unit (source file) are initialized in the order in which they are defined.

or

> Within the same compilation unit the order is well defined: The same order as definition.

etc.

But where can I see these words in the standard of C++? I would like to get a one or few concrete paragraph's where such behavior is described. I can not find it myself, and I do not know who to ask.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/#basic

Comment: I find it very difficult to believe no thread here cites this. In which case, this would be a clear duplicate, presumably along with many others linked to such a thread. Maybe someone needs to edit such canonical thread(s) to be more searchable...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ## 6.6.3  Dynamic initialization of non-local variables  [[basic.start.dynamic](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic)]
>
> 1. Dynamic initialization of a non-local
>      variable with static storage duration is unordered if the variable is
>      an implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, is
>      partially-ordered if the variable is an inline variable that is not an
>      implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, and otherwise is
>      ordered. [ Note: An explicitly specialized non-inline static data
>      member or variable template specialization has ordered initialization.
>      — end note ]
> 2. Dynamic initialization of non-local variables V and W
>      with static storage duration are ordered as follows:
>
>    - If V and
>        W have ordered initialization and V is defined before W within a
>        single translation unit, the initialization of V is sequenced before
>        the initialization of W.
>    - If V
>        has partially-ordered initialization, W does not have unordered
>        initialization, and V is defined before W in every translation unit in
>        which W is defined, then
>
>      - if the program starts a thread
>          (4.7) other than the main thread (6.6.1), the initialization of V
>          strongly happens before the initialization of W;
>      - otherwise,
>          the initialization of V is sequenced before the initialization of W.
>    - Otherwise, if the program starts a thread other than the main
>        thread before either V or W is initialized, it is unspecified in which
>        threads the initializations of V and W occur; the initializations are
>        unsequenced if they occur in the same thread.
>    - Otherwise, the
>        initializations of V and W are indeterminately sequenced.

Quoted from N4659, formatting adjusted to work with the markdown supported here.

For the exact definition of dynamic initialization, see the preceding subsesction 6.6.2 [basic.start.static].

Comment: My standard-seeking speed is not up to par. +1.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think is that what I looking for :)

Comment: For completeness wrt. the question's title, static linkage does not alter the initialization behaviour.

Comment: @Quentin for completeness, whether the rule described above apply to a variable that is statically initialized? Like int a; or int b = 5; ?

Comment: @adziri that's in the section right above that one, [[basic.start.static](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static)]. I'm unsure whether another static variable can be used in a constant expression for static initialization though.

Comment: @Quentin I mean that rule about 'global variables initialized in the order in which they are defined' working for static and dynamic initialization? Like here https://rextester.com/NWP34030

Comment: @adziri well, "static initialization" amounts to "baked-in at compile time", so the question is whether static-initialized objects can refer to each other -- if not, then the order is irrelevant since they are independent.

Comment: @Quentin 'whether static-initialized objects can refer to each other' -- if yes, than? (in referencing means like int a = 5; int& b = a; ?)