# Visual C++: Is global variables initialization order deterministic during DLL loading?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, global-variables, initialization-order

Assume I build the simple DLL, consisting of two translation units:

first

```
// foo.cpp
struct Foo
{
  //...
} g_foo;
// ... other stuff
```

and second

```
// bar.cpp
struct Bar
{
  //...
} g_bar;
// ... other stuff
```

I'm aware of the fact that C++ standard doesn't specify the order of global variables initialization. The question is: once I have the built Windows DLL, is the order of global variables initialization performed during `LoadLibrary` call deterministic (every `LoadLibrary` call will launch initialization of the variables `g_foo` and `g_bar` in the same order) or it may depend on some loader/system settings?

Comment: As described in the documentation of [DllMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain), and linked general best practices, of what you can do inside of it: only `Kernel32.dll` can be assumed as loaded, inside of `DllMain`. Hence: the actual load order of libraries is not deterministic.

Comment: Regardless of how many translation units are used to create it, a DLL can only have one DllMain function, and that's what Windows calls in order to initialize the DLL. From that point on, the order of initialization options in your DLL are determined by the code within the DLL itself. So yes, if your DLL doesn't change, the order of initialization should be consistent.

But I would certainly agree that you need to be very careful about what you do at DllMain time, which includes static variable initializers.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I meant the order of initialization of global variables inside the same library. Added this to question description.

Comment: @undermind I don't know if that answers your immediate problem, but I remember searching sometime ago, about when global objects are initialized in a DLL: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141017-00/?p=43823 ; And this is more generic, when the global variables are initialized, in regards to C++ standard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159044/static-global-variables-initialization-order (there are multiple questions along the similar lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm aware of the fact that C++ standard doesn't specify the order of
> global variables initialization.
> To be precise, it does when the global variables are within a single translation unit:

[Ordered dynamic initialization, which applies to all other non-local
variables: within a single translation unit, initialization of these
variables is always sequenced in exact order their definitions
appear in the source code.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

Your DLL code above, where you have two different global variables within two different translation units, will result in **two different .OBJ files** before link. Then, when the .OBJ files are linked together to form a .DLL, the C++ "pre-main" runtime code will be attached to the .DLL. When the .DLL is bound to the address space of the process by process-launch or by `LoadLibrary`, this stub  code will have access to a table within your DLL, which, before invocation of DllMain, it will iterate-through, invoking link-time-synthesized static non-member functions in the table, each non-member function having the job of running a class member constructor in the table for the corresponding global object. Naturally, during removal of DLL from your process address space, either by process-exit or by `FreeLibrary`, the non-member functions will be similarly invoked, but in reverse (LIFO) order.

Given that this table is "baked" into the .DLL by LINK.EXE, the order of construction for global variables within the DLL, whether they are from same translation unit, or different, will be predetermined. It will not be *predictable* before link-time, as you noted, but whatever it becomes *after* link-time, that is what it will remain for the life of the .DLL because only LINK.EXE has the ability to construct that global variable constructor table, and once it is constructed, it is constructed.

If anyone is wondering which comes first: the construction of global variables, or the programmer-supplied DllMain, it is the former. The C++ run-time code is what invokes the programmer-supplied DllMain, as can be seen in the [link provided by @Algirdas Preidžius](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141017-00/?p=43823).