# Multi Threaded and templated singleton race condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton, pthreads, race-condition

I'm trying to create a multi threaded and templated singleton as part of my advance c++ study. I've been told I have a race condition in my code and after hours of trying to figure it out i can't find it.

I won't write the whole class (though it's a simple one) but the exact location where I've been focused down to:

```
template <class T>
void Singleton<T>::onceFunction()
{
    static T instanceObject; 
    Singleton<T>::instance = &instanceObject;
}

template <class T>
T& Singleton<T>::getInstance()
{
    while (0 == Singleton::instance)
    {
        static pthread_once_t  once_control = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
        pthread_once(&once_control, Singleton<T>::onceFunction);  
    }
    return *Singleton::instance;
}
```

I'm using pthread_once() since I'm not compiling with c++11.

Comment: You might find this useful: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962880/is-c-static-member-variable-initialization-thread-safe)

Comment: When is `once_control` initialized -- and on which thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show is designed to protect/serialize the initailization of

```
static T instanceObject;
```

as defined in `Singleton<T>::onceFunction()`.  In order to achieve that you use `pthread_once`.  However, you have declared the `pthread_once_t` flag `once_control` at function/block scope with static storage...

```
static pthread_once_t  once_control = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
```

Hence, I think the initialization of `once_control` suffers from the same race condition that your code is designed to solve for `instanceObject`.

Make `once_control` a static member of `Singleton<T>` instead.

**Note:** Your code also assumes the assignment...

```
Singleton<T>::instance = &instanceObject;
```

is atomic.