# Singleton in java vs. Singleton in C++

Tags: java, c++, singleton

In Java I can create a Singleton like this (as long as it doesn't throw as exception):

```
private static Singleton m_this = new Singleton();
```

This is very convenient because it's inherently thread safe.

Can I do something similar in C++?

Comment: See: https://ideone.com/whiUhA

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames that way, you're getting a local copy of `instance` every time you call `getInstance`.

Comment: What? I'm getting the same exact instance.. It's static. I just forgot to make the function `getInstance` itself static is all.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames, I think it's not thread safe (in contrary to the Java line, which is...)

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames you're __not__ returning the static instance. You're returning a copy of it, since the function doesn't return a __reference__ in your code.

Comment: See the accepted answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711920/how-to-implement-multithread-safe-singleton-in-c11-without-using-mutex

Comment: Oh sorry @PawełStawarz I didn't notice that.. I guess my example is bad. +1 from me. I was trying to write what Martin J wrote as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of making a singleton with thread-safe initialization, guaranteed by the standard as of C++11. is:

```
class SomeSingleton {
  public:
    static SomeSingleton& instance() {
      static SomeSingleton instance_;
      return instance_;
    }

  private:
  SomeSingleton() {
    ...
  }
};
```

This is thread-safe, because [local static variable initialization is thread-safe in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11). The relevant standard document, [N3485](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf), says in section 6.7.4:

> such a variable is initialized the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization. [...] If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.

with footnote:

> The implementation must not introduce any deadlock around execution of the initializer.

You can abstract into a nice template base class with CRTP:

```
//Singleton template definition
template <typename TDerived>
class Singleton {
  static_assert(is_base_of<Singleton, TDerived>::value, "Singleton: unexpected Derived template parameter");
  public:
    static TDerived& instance() {
      static TDerived instance_;
      return instance_;
    }

  protected:
  Singleton() {
  }
};

// SomeSingleton definition, using the Singleton template
class SomeSingleton : public Singleton<SomeSingleton> {
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If by *Singleton*, you mean a **real** [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) (which I'm not sure is the same you gave an example of, because you still could create a second `Singleton` instance and assign it to a different variable), the answer is **yes**. You can create a singleton object using the **factory pattern**.

```
class factory;
class singleton{
   singleton(){}; // private constructor
   friend class factory;
};

class factory{
   private:
      static std::shared_ptr<singleton> object;

   public:
      static singleton& getSingleton(){
         if(object)
            return *object;
         object = new singleton;
         return *object;
      }
};
```

Instead of making a dedicated `factory` class, you could make `getSingleton` a `static` member function of `singleton` itself too. Just remember to make the constructor `private`, so the user can't create multiple copies.

Comment: That destructor on `factory` is very misleading. I'd have provided another `static` method for destroying the singleton.

Comment: @yzl you're right, a `shared_ptr` is way safer in this case.

Comment: @PawełStawarz, this solution is not thread safe (in contrary to the Java line in my question...), is there no way to create a thread-safe singleton inline (like in Java)?

Comment: @user1028741 if you want to make it thread safe, combine it with `std::atomic`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/

Answer (score 1):

Also, on top of answer given by Paweł Stawarz, I would add that copy constructor, move constructor (C++11), overloaded assignment operator and destructor should be private too.

```
class singleton{
   singleton(){}; // private constructor
   ~singleton(){}; // private destructor
   singleton(const singleton &src){}; // private copy constructor
   singleton(const singleton&& src){}; // private move constructor for C++11
   singleton& operator = (const singleton& src){return *this;} // private = operator
   friend class factory;
};
```

Being private, copy constructor, move constructor (C++11), overloaded assignment operator and destructor cannot be called from outside to clone an existing copy and also to destroy a copy just created.