# Problems with DLL compiled with VS2015 XP toolset

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015, windows-xp

I have two problems with DLL compiled with VS2015 XP toolset when called from non VS2015 exe.

First and most serious is that using in such DLL-s tls variables (like statics declared inside function results in GPE on XP/Server 2003R2). Works fine on Windows 7+ and/or when called from VS2015 exe. Looks like something in runtime isn't initialized when called that way.

The second problem is with side by side installation of W10SDK/runtime DLL. Everything works fine with EXE but doesn't load from DLL path. You have either to install runtime or to copy DLLs to exe directory.

Can anyone suggest a solution especially to the first problem (second is annoying but can be handled).

Comment: That is not unlikely, VS2015 is the first one that implements the thread-safety guarantee that C++11 demands for such variables.  Its CRT uses several winapi functions that are not available on XP and tries to limp along when it discovers that they are not available.  They relate to threading, locale and, you guessed it, TLS.  Particularly the missing FlsAlloc() is quite detrimental btw.  How well this was tested on XP is sort of guessable.  Use connect.microsoft.com to report bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Found a duplicate for first problem with workaround
[Crash in CAtlStringMgr::GetInstance under Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633398/crash-in-catlstringmgrgetinstance-under-windows-xp)

What concerns second one -  solved it with writing a VS2012 DLL proxy that chdirs to proxy directory, loads the library and then chdirs back (and then calls through all calls to VS2015 DLL. But would be glad to find more elegant solution