# Variable declared 'static' crashes on Windows XP

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, windows-xp

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour on Windows XP. I'm compiling my project on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2017. When I compile the individual sources I pass `/D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` to `cl` to make sure my program runs on XP.

Still, when I try to run it on XP I get a strange crash in the following code (which doesn't use any Windows APIs, FWIW):

```
void CPDF_StreamContentParser::OnOperator(const CFX_ByteStringC& op) {
  static const OpCodes s_OpCodes = InitializeOpCodes();

  auto it = s_OpCodes.find(op.GetID());
  if (it != s_OpCodes.end())
    (this->*it->second)();
}
```

On Windows 7 and 10 the code works fine but on XP it crashes. After some debugging I found out that `static` is the culprit. Changing line 2 into this makes the crash go away and everything works fine on XP too:

```
/*static*/ const OpCodes s_OpCodes = InitializeOpCodes();
```

But it doesn't make any sense to me that `static` should be a problem here. Does anybody have an explanation why the code crashes on XP when using `static` and works fine when omitting `static`? It doesn't make sense to me.

FWIW, `InitializeOpCodes()` is declared as follows:

```
using OpCodes = std::map<uint32_t, void (CPDF_StreamContentParser::*)()>;
static OpCodes InitializeOpCodes();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just because a program crashes on a particular line doesn't mean that it's where the bug is. C++ does not work this way. A bug that corrupts memory can be anywhere in your code, and all that an extra `static` object does is slightly change the internal memory layout of your running executable's objects, after linking, so that the memory corruption results in a crash here. You will have to figure out where in your code the bug is, and fix it.

Comment: On XP your program runs in a vastly different runtime environment.  One consequence of using a CRT version >= 2012 is that the low fragmentation heap is not enabled on XP.  So if your program has a latent memory corruption bug then it can easily show its ugly face on XP   That `static` keyword is very relevant as well.  By C++11 rules, such variables are now initialized in a thread-safe way.  New CRT versions depend on several winapi functions that are not available on XP, related to threading and culture.  It tries to limp along without them, ymmv.

Comment: @Hans: Maybe I should have added that I'm compiling with `/MT` in order to be independent from MSVCRT. Would using `/MD` make a difference?

Comment: @Sam: The code is actually Google's PDFium. So not exactly easy to debug.

Comment: Unless you are the author of "Goole's PDFium", whatever it is, you most likely have your own code somewhere in there. That's where the bug is. Of course, even Google can write bugs, but the most likely place where the bug lives would be your code.

Comment: @Sam: My code is minimal. I've already isolated the issue and my own code is just 10 lines calling PDFium APIs. No bugs in there. If I understand Hans correctly, the problem could also be in Visual C 2017 generating code that could cause problems on XP. That was my suspicion as well. PDFium uses all sorts of c++11 features and I'm not sure if all this can seamlessly run on XP.

Comment: when you use local `static` initialization - modern *CL* compiler add special calls to `_Init_thread_header` and `_Init_thread_footer` functions - look asm code and *thread_safe_statics.cpp*. it try implement [`InitOnceExecuteOnce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683493(v=vs.85).aspx). functional. obvious on xp call to  `_Init_thread_header` or `_Init_thread_footer` is fail

Comment: Yes, /MT does make a difference.  Once nasty detail is that it makes it much harder to clean-up thread-local state.  The CRT depends on an FlsAlloc() callback to do this as safe as possible, not available on XP.   The code-gen for `static` uses thread-local state.  But more relevant is that you cannot depend on the googlers ever testing /MT code, using /MD is strongly advisable.

Comment: @RbMm: You're the man. Researching `thread_safe_statics.cpp` brought me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32776479/1197719). This is exactly the issue I'm seeing because my project is actually a DLL. I then compiled PDFium using `/Zc:threadSafeInit-` and voila, the crash goes away on XP. So it was a Visual C compatibility issue with XP after all. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Andreas - yes, this is because modern crt almost not support xp as well. also you can as solution move line `static const OpCodes s_OpCodes = InitializeOpCodes();` out of the function - as result it will be executed when dll loaded (but not when function first time called). `/Zc:threadSafeInit-` will be ok only if you sure that no more one thread call your function in concurrent. or you need provide functional of `InitOnceExecuteOnce` yourself. here thin question and you need good understand what you doing

Comment: I'm not using multithreading so `/Zc:threadSafeInit-` should be fine. Just one more question: My project also contains lots of C sources. Do I need to use `/Zc:threadSafeInit-` on the C sources too or is it just needed for C++ sources?

Comment: [/Zc:threadSafeInit (Thread-safe Local Static Initialization)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-threadsafeinit-thread-safe-local-static-initialization) applied both to *c* and *c++* and usually set to all project but not to separate files

Comment: however you link faster related to old crt. and documentation also old. modern crt not use more *TLS* or *FLS*. if you look for disasm code i guess you view exactly `_Init_thread_header` and `_Init_thread_footer` calls around `InitializeOpCodes();` but not `__tls_index` or something related to tls/fls