# C++11 Magic Statics Workaround in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2012, initialization

I have some objects defined as global, which means their constructor are entered before program start or under DllMain(). This causes some issues, and that is why I want to move them to local static.

Our main project are mainly under Visual Studio 2012. According to the these post.

- [“Magic static” singleton crashing when referenced in static destruction phase of another translation unit"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36189708/2210478)
- [Support For C++11/14/17 Features (Modern C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)

The Magic Statics is not implemented in Visual Studio 2012 (until VS 2015). So the local static variable initialization is not automatically protected from concurrent access by compiler.

What is a suitable workaround or solution for this case?

---

Here is what I tried:

Add a lock to protect. But if the variable initialized before the function is entered, my lock may be useless...

```
// data object
struct Cat
{
    Cat()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ <<  "\n";
    }
};

// lock mutex for singleton getter
static std::mutex getcat_m;

// singleton getter
Cat& GetCat(){
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ <<  " In\n";

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(getcat_m);
    static Cat cat;

    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ <<  " Out\n";
    return cat;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ <<  " In\n";
    Cat& cat = GetCat();
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ <<  " Out\n";

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

It actually shows as expected. The constructor is called after function is entered.

```
main In
GetCat In
Cat::Cat
GetCat Out
main Out
```

But I am not sure whether this is a suitable solution.

Comment: You can also give  `std::call_once` a try. Looks like it's also reccommended  [18.2.4 Use std::call_once rather than the Double-Checked Locking pattern](http://www.codingstandard.com/rule/18-2-4-use-stdcall_once-rather-than-the-double-checked-locking-pattern/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [A. A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8918119/a-a) in comment for the link [18.2.4 Use std::call_once rather than the Double-Checked Locking pattern](http://www.codingstandard.com/rule/18-2-4-use-stdcall_once-rather-than-the-double-checked-locking-pattern/).

I referenced the example from the Guildline, and rewrite my singleton getter code as the following.

```
// Cat.cpp
static std::once_flag once_Cat;
static Cat* gpCat = nullptr;
void init_Cat() { gpCat = new Cat(); }

Cat& GetCat() {
    std::call_once(once_Cat, init_Cat);
    return *gpCat;
}
```