# Difference between Singleton implemention using pointer and using static object

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

EDIT: Sorry my question was not clear, why do books/articles prefer implementation#1 over implementation#2?

What is the actual advantage of using pointer in implementation of Singleton class vs using a static object? Why do most books prefer this

```
class Singleton
{
  private:

    static Singleton *p_inst;
    Singleton();

  public:

    static Singleton * instance()
    {
      if (!p_inst)
      {
        p_inst = new Singleton();
      }

      return p_inst;
    }
};
```

over this

```
class Singleton
{
  public:
    static Singleton& Instance()
    {
        static Singleton inst;
        return inst;
    }

  protected:
    Singleton(); // Prevent construction
    Singleton(const Singleton&); // Prevent construction by copying
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&); // Prevent assignment
    ~Singleton(); // Prevent unwanted destruction
};
```

Comment: The second one is inherently thread-safe, and also won't report memory leaks if a memory-leak checker is used.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - only guaranteed threadsafe in fully conformant C++11, AFAIK.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The second one is inherently thread-safe? How? What if two threads call the function concurrently? When does the static local object get created (and by which thread)?

Comment: @Nawaz: It gets created exactly once, in one of those threads, and is only returned after it has been created.

Comment: @Nawaz : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11

Comment: @Anon - which books - Can you give an example?

Comment: @ROddy Gang of Four .Page 129, AdDison-Wesley edition

Comment: @Anon: The C++ in Gang of Four should not be considered as even remotely indicative of good style. The book is rather old, and it is about patterns, rather than about the details of their implementations.

Comment: @Anon: That book was written almost twenty years ago. Both the language, and our understanding of how to use it effectively, have changed considerably since then.

Comment: @Mankarse , I thought that was the go-to book for anything related to Design patterns? Which book would you recommend for C++/Design patterns then? Thanks

Comment: @MikeSeymour Fair point. but there are other articles too.

Comment: Singleton use is bad design most of the time it gets used.

Comment: @Anon: It's the go-to book as a catalogue - not implementation - of some OO design patterns that were common and useful in the early nineties. Most of them still are. You should view the code (which is just sample code, not a reference implementation)  more as an historic artifact illustrating how people wrote C++ in a different era.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> why do books/articles prefer implementation#1 over implementation#2?

Because most articles describing the Singleton anti-pattern don't fully understand all the hidden dangers when trying to implement it safely in C++. It's surprisingly difficult to get it right.

> What is the actual advantage of using pointer in implementation of Singleton class vs using a static object?

Using a pointer, with `new` but no `delete`, ensures that the object will never be destroyed, so there is no danger of accessing it after its lifetime has ended. Combined with the "lazy" creation, the first time that it's accessed, this guarantees that all accesses are to a valid object. The disadvantages are that creation is not thread-safe, and that the object and any resources it acquires are not released at the end of the program.

Using a local static object, creation is thread-safe on any compiler that supports the C++11 threading model; also, the object will be destroyed at the end of the program. However, it is possible to access the object after its destruction (e.g. from the destructor of another static object), which could lead to nasty bugs.

The best option is to avoid static data, and globally-accessible data, as much as possible. In particular, never use the Singleton anti-pattern; it combines global, static data with weird instantiation restrictions that make testing unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it explains the difference and why. But upvotes to everyone. Thanks

Comment: +1 for calling Singleton and anti-pattern. I don't necessarily agree with "never use" but certainly "rarely use".

Comment: "...ensures that the object will never be destroyed" I just read the gof singleton chapter and was a bit surprised that they dont mention at all the destruction of the singleton. Is it because it really doesnt matter or did they simply forget to discuss it?

Answer (score 11):

The second version (using a local static variable) has significant advantages.

It does not require use of the free-store, and so will not be detected as a memory leak. It is thread-safe (in `C++11`). It is shorter and simpler.

The only downsides are that it is impossible to make it portably threadsafe (for pre-C++11 compilers), and that it does not give you the option of explicitly destroying the singleton instance.

Comment: Yes, that is the question, why do books prefer the first one over the second one? Does the first one have any advantage that the second implementation does not?

Comment: But the disadvantage is non-deterministic destruction, so if you have many of these you cannot select the order in which they are destroyed.

Comment: @CashCow: Indeed. However, I weep for the program in which that is important.

Answer (score 5):

The second example is known by the name "Meyers' Singleton", because it was published first in either "Effective C++", or "More Effective C++". I'm not sure which one, but both were published after "Design Patterns" - so the Gang of Four might just as well have been unaware of the second pattern when their book was written.

Also, the first approach is much more standard for other languages - you can do the first one in Java or C#, but not the second, so people coming from different backgrounds could be another reason for the first one to be more famous.

On the technical side, with the first approach you can control when the singleton is destroyed, but this could also bring you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 4):

I'd **always** prefer the second, but the first does have a couple of potentially interesting advantages:-

- Clarity - the checking of the pointer being null is effectively
  what the compiler does under the hood when constructing static
  objects. From a 'learning' perspective, it's instructive to
  understand what's happening when you use static objects in method
  scope.
- Lazy Allocation - in the first case, the Singleton object is
  heap-allocated. If your function never runs, the object is never
  constructed and never consumes memory. But, in the second case,
  memory is assigned by the linker to hold the object before the
  program starts, even though 'construction' is lazy.

Comment: In the second case memory is not allocated for locally declared static objects (assuming Instance() is not called) as opposed to static member variable. It can be verified by adding a print statement in the constructor.

Comment: @sandeep. You're confusing construction with allocation. The object will typically be statically allocated by the linker, so is consuming memory even though it hasn't been constructed yet.

Answer (score 3):

The second one has non-deterministic destruction. The first one, you are in control as to when you delete the pointer, if at all.

The first construct is not thread-safe, of course, but can be made so with `boost::call_once` (or `std::call_once` if available)

The second construct was common enough that many compilers made it thread-safe even if technically by the standard it isn't (although by the standard the object should only be created once, I'm not sure about the standard's view on completion of the construction before another thread uses it).

If there is no issue with the order of destruction then you can go ahead and use the static version, as long as your compiler guarantees it as thread-safe.

Comment: The initialisation of local statics is thread safe in all versions of the language that have threads. (But the point stands that it is not threadsafe in many pre-C++11 compilers).

Comment: C++11 has [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) and [`std::once_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag).

Comment: static version is thread-safe with most compilers, it wasn't always. C++11 standard is that compilers must make it thread-safe. Previous standard never said anything about threads.

Answer (score 1):

One advantage is that you do not have to check whether the singleton has already been instantiated.

Another is that you do not have to worry about de-allocating any memory.

Answer (score -3):

How about a non-local static? Anyone see a problem with this?

```
class Singleton
{
    static Singleton singleton;
    Singleton();
    // etc

public:
    static Singleton &Instance() { return singleton; }
};

Singleton Singleton::singleton;

// etc
```

Comment: Um, yes...there is a **fundamental** problem with this. For instance, where would you define the instance? How would you ensure it was instantiated before any other translation unit tried to access it? Trick questions: The problems resulting from using global `static`s are _precisely **why**_ a function-local instance is used (in either way illustrated by the OP) as a 'guard'. Just go read about the well-known "static initialisation order fiasco"