# Memory Leak with Singleton Implemented for Multithreaded Environment

Tags: c++, singleton

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance() {

if (pInstance == 0) {

    Lock lock;

    if (pInstance == 0) {

        Singleton* temp = new Singleton; // initialize to temp
        pInstance = temp; // assign temp to pInstance
   }
  }
```

Suppose compiler is not optimizing the redundant temp.
Thread A is in and allocated and constructed the Singleton object, this object is pointed by temp.
Now A is preempted just after that.
Now thread B gets the lock, get into in and check that pInstance is NULL.
It will also create the Singleton object and over writes the existing pointer. I guess there is a memory leak now. What is your opinion ?
Complete source is here:
Code Reference:http://erdani.com/publications/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf

Comment: Please read the article you linked, again.

Answer (score 1):

No. When A is interrupted, it sill owns the lock. Thus B has to wait until A releases the lock, but then pInstance is assigned and B's second check for null will fail.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, the standard stipulates in paragraph 6.7 that:

> such a variable is initialized the first time control passes through
> its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the
> completion of its initialization. [...] If control enters the
> declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the
> concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.
>
> The implementation must not introduce any deadlock around execution of
> the initializer.

This leads to the following very simple and thread-safe singleton method implementation:

```
Singleton* Singleton::instance() {
    Singleton instance;
    return &instance;
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11) for more details on which compilers support this.