# Construct on first use + forced initialization to solve static initialization order fiasco?

Tags: c++, multithreading

It is known that [static initialization order fiasco (SIOF)](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html) can be solved by using [construct on first use idiom (COFU)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Construct_On_First_Use). However, this solution may introduce [the issue with race conditions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/08/85901.aspx) when the variable is being initialized from multiple threads.

I tried to avoid both SIOF and race conditions in my project in a following way. I used COFU. And I forced initialization of target variable by using non-local variable (`c_unusedNonLocal`) in cpp. Thus, thanks to `c_unusedNonLocal`, even if there are no non-locals which access target variable via `B::getA` it is initialized anyway. What is important, it is initialized before `main` in a single thread. So, with read-only access there should be no race conditions and no SIOF.

Is this a feasible solution? Are there any possible pitfalls or I mistaken about initialization in a single thread or whatever?

Thanks.

a.h

```
struct A
{
    A() {}
};
```

b.h

```
struct B
{
    static const A& getA();
};
```

b.cpp

```
// force initialization before 'main'
// assuming that this happens in a single thread (thus no race conditions)
static const A& c_unusedNonLocal = B::getA();

const A& B::getA()
{
    static const A* result = new A();
    return *result;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    // _read only_ access via B::getA is now thread safe
    // because object is guaranteed (?) to be initialized before main
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "this solution may introduce the issue with race conditions when the variable is being initialized from multiple threads." No longer the case in C++11.

Comment: See more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11

Comment: (+1) because: maybe seemm irrelevant for some, but the added "multithreading" tag reinforces the scenario, that also applies to non "multithreading" cases.