# Static variable lifetimes, file-scope vs. function scope

Tags: c++, static, g++

suppose I have a `.cpp` file:

```
static Foo aFoo;

Foo& staticFoo(){
    return aFoo; 
}

Foo& singletonFoo(){ // not thread safe in c++-03
    static Foo staticFoo;
    return staticFoo;
}
```

and a `.h` file that exposes these functions (but not `aFoo` directly).

1. Am I certain that `aFoo` is initialized prior to `staticFoo`?
2. Am I certain that `staticFoo` is destroyed after `aFoo`?
3. Am I certain that `aFoo` is destroyed after any automatic storage duration
   variables in my program?

Comment: Why do you think that `singletonFoo` is not thread safe?

Comment: @ecatmur, [It wasn't prior to C++11.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11)

Comment: @ecatmur Because C++98 doesn't guarantee static local initialization to be thread safe (since it doesn't mention threads at all).

Comment: www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. If someone calls `singletonFoo` from another translation unit during static initialization then it's unspecified.
2. No because the destruction happens in reverse order of construction and we already established that construction is not guaranteed.
3. `aFoo` will be destroyed after all local/automatic variables.

Comment: non-static  means "not declared with static", i.e. automatic storage duration variables.