# Where are non-static member of a static object allocated?

Tags: c++, object

I have this code and I wonder about memory allocation.

```
 void f(){
        static A a;
        //Other things...
    }

    class A {
        public:
           A();
        private:
            AnotherObjectType anotherObject;
    };
```

where will the `anotherObject` be allocated ? in the `static` code segment or elsewhere ? is there a risk for `anotherObject` to be overwritten ? (`f` will be called several times).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All non-heap objects will be in the static segment, inside the static A instance of f().

Concerning overwriting, this could happen in older C/C++ if you used various singleton idioms in multi-threaded code. But e.g. newer gcc versions use the new standard requirements for automatic thread-safe initialization of static objects. See e.g. [Is local static variable initialization thread-safe in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11)

Comment: The only answer so far which points out difference in behavior of static variables in post and pre C++11

Comment: More precisely, by non-*heap* you actually mean non-*dynamic*. The dynamically allocated objects can also be in the static segment if a custom allocator is used. "Heap" is an implementation detail which just happens to  be most used.

Comment: Beware that I don't think Visual C++ implements thread safe static initialisation (magic statics) before VS2015.

Comment: @Johann Gerell: Good point, knowing about custom allocators is important.

Answer (score 1):

Memory is either *statically* or *dynamically* allocated. Dynamic allocation is what you get when allocating memory at runtime, with for instance `new` and `malloc`. Static allocation is "the rest". Memory for class member variables are allocated with the class instance, so if it is statically allocated, the members end up in the same part of the memory, and if it is dynamically allocated, the members end up where the dynamic memory resides. This is also true for pointer member variables, but the actual memory it points at can be either dynamically (`new` and `malloc`) or statically allocated.

```
int i = 0;
int* pi = &i;     // pi points at statically allocated memory
pi = new int(0);  // pi points at dynamically allocated memory
```

So, if you have a static class instance, memory for it and its members is *usually* allocated in the code segment, but that is an implementation detail.

If the member is a pointer, which points at dynamically allocated memory, that memory will be **where the used allocator decides**. The "heap" is the most common implementation detail of dynamically allocated memory, which you *normally* get when using `new` and `malloc`, but **a custom allocator can be used** that controls memory elsewhere, even in the code segment.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `a` is a static variable and is only declared once, that means the `A a;` statement is only execute one time. The scope of the variable is above the function `f` scope. The field `anotherObject` is within the allocation of 
the A object.

See example with counting:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class AnotherObjectType {};

class A {
public:
   A(){count = 0;};
    int count;
private:
    AnotherObjectType anotherObject;
};

 A f(){
    static A a;
    a.count++;
    //Other things...
    return a;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    A a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a = f();
        std::cout << "Count: " << a.count  << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Working Example: http://ideone.com/USqeEZ

See also: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/

Answer (score 0):

```
void f(){
    /// this created in static segment - that's obviously for you
    static A a;
    //Other things...
}

class A {
    public:
       A();
    private:
        /// anotherObject is not pointer but explicit part of A,
        /// so it won't be created in heap or anywhere else,
        /// but in the same memory segment as an instance of A.
        AnotherObjectType anotherObject;
};
```

So, anotherObject wouldn't be overwritten because `static A a` create one instance of A in static segment and any other instances will be craeted in other segments depending in what segment you will create it.

Comment: why minus without explanation in comments? what's wrong?

Comment: I upped marked you, as I'm irritated with the "kind person" that downmarked you without specifying why... You have a couple of spelling mistakes, and things aren't that clear, but I get the picture.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. And excuse me for my bad english. )

Answer (score 0):

Although both called **static**, a static member is different from a static local variable.

A static member is shared in the class.  Every instance of this class refers to the same member.

A static local variable is initialized once, and is not destroyed when the function returns.

In your code, non-static members are stored in the instance `a`, and `a` persists beyond function returns.