# Is it better to declare the static singleton object outside of the static instance getter method?

Tags: c++, singleton

While reading the most upvoted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/10400598) explaining the Singleton Pattern in C++, I realized some performance issues. The answer proposes the below form for implementing the pattern.

```
class SomeClass {
public: /** Singleton **/
    static SomeClass& instance() {
        static SomeClass singleInstance;

        return singleInstance;
    };

private: 
    SomeClass() = default;
    SomeClass(const SomeClass&) = delete;
};
```

When I implement the Singleton in the suggested form, the assembly of the program is as follows. Looking at the output below, I can easily say that the `instance()` method includes a branch to test whether it is the first call to the function or not *(e.g. whether the static instance was created or not)*.

```
SomeClass::instance():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR guard variable for SomeClass::instance()::singleInstance[rip]
        test    al, al
        sete    al
        test    al, al
        je      .L2
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:guard variable for SomeClass::instance()::singleInstance
        call    __cxa_guard_acquire
        test    eax, eax
        setne   al
        test    al, al
        je      .L2
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:guard variable for SomeClass::instance()::singleInstance
        call    __cxa_guard_release
.L2:
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:SomeClass::instance()::singleInstance
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Then, I tried to separate the declaration of the static object from the static `instance()` method like below.

```
class SomeClass {
public: /** Singleton **/
    static SomeClass& instance() {
        return singleInstance;
    };

private: 
    SomeClass() = default;
    SomeClass(const SomeClass&) = delete;
    
    static SomeClass singleInstance;
};

SomeClass SomeClass::singleInstance; // In the source file
```

The output of the second program is, as expected, different from the first one. It doesn't include a branch that tests the existence of the Singleton object.

```
SomeClass::instance():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:SomeClass::singleInstance
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

I've found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396373/singleton-instance-as-static-field-vs-static-variable-in-getinstance-method) explaining the reason for using the in-class static definition of the Singleton instance.

Is it really better to declare the Singleton object outside of the static getter function if the static initialization order isn't a problem?

Comment: Given that, at the time of writing, a CPU will execute billions of instructions per second, I'm not sure the perceived overhead of a branch (which a sensible branch predictor will obviate), will ever persuade over the advantages of localising the `static`. Good analysis and question though, +1.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks for the appreciation. I've linked a similar question with explanatory answers. Looks like the solution is highly dependent on the case. If the Singleton objects are referring to each other, then the [static initialization fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) might occur. By the way, I'm a guy who tries save each and every cycle on embedded systems :)