# Thread safe local variable

Tags: c++, thread-safety, c++14

```
void HelloWorld()
{
   static std::atomic<short> static_counter = 0;
   short val = ++static_counter; // or val = static_counter++;
}
```

If this function is called from two threads,

Can the local variable `val` be `1` in both threads? or (0 if `static_counter++` is used?)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11

Comment: @user2807083 That is not the question. I know static_counter will be initialized safely. The c++11 standard requires that. I'm talking about val, which is not static..

Comment: I think here it is nothing about your local `var`, but all about ++ operator applied to static variable. So I think the right question is "Is increment of atomic variable thread safe?"

Comment: Your question is about the thread safety of the *static* variable, not the local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Can the local variable val be 1 in both threads?

No. `++static_counter` is equivalent to:

```
 fetch_add(1)+1
```

which cannot return *same* value for two (or more) threads *because* [`fetch_add`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add) is executed atomically.

Comment: Does the same apply for static_counter++ ?

Comment: Yes. That is equivalent to `fetch_add(1)`. Please read [the doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith) for more details.

Comment: There are two things involved, the construction of the `static_counter` object and the increment operation. The latter is guaranteed to be atomic, but according to the link in the comments, construction isn't.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Construction is guaranteed by C++11 spec, by the core language.

Comment: @nawaz there are global variabke ctor order problems: if called prior to main, what guaranteee that the atomic has been constructed is there?

Comment: @Phantom Saying that one operation can be implemented as two divisible operations is the same as saying the operation isn't atomic. But we know the operation is atomic.

Comment: @Yakk: I think the `static` keyword guarantees that no two threads can enter into the constructor.  See the quote from the spec [in the accepted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11) (and the comments as well)

Comment: @nawaz sorry, they edited since I had read it.  It did not used to be static.

Answer (score 2):

No. The only way `val` could have the same value in both threads is if the two atomic operations overlapped. By definition, atomic operations cannot overlap.