# magic statics: similar constructs, interesting non-obvious uses?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

C++11 introduced threadsafe local static initialization, aka "magic statics": [Is local static variable initialization thread-safe in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11#answer-8102145)

In particular, the spec says:

> If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is
>   being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion
>   of the initialization.

So there's an implicit mutex lock here.  This is very interesting, and seems like an anomaly-- that is, I don't know of any other implicit mutexes built into c++ (i.e. mutex semantics without any use of things like std::mutex).  Are there any others, or is this unique in the spec?

I'm also curious whether magic static's implicit mutex (or other implicit mutexes, if there are any) can be leveraged to implement other synchronization primitives.  For example, I see that they can be used to implement std::call_once, since this:

```
std::call_once(onceflag, some_function);
```

can be expressed as this:

```
static int dummy = (some_function(), 0);
```

Note, however, that the magic static version is more limited than std::call_once, since with std::call_once you could re-initialize onceflag and so use the code multiple times per program execution, whereas with magic statics, you really only get to use it once per program execution.

That's the only somewhat non-obvious use of magic statics that I can think of.

Is it possible to use magic static's implicit mutex to implement other synchronization primitives, e.g. a general std::mutex, or other useful things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialization of block-scope `static` variables is the only place where the *language* requires synchronization. Several library functions require synchronization, but aren't directly synchronization functions (e.g. `atexit`).

Since the synchronization on the initialization of a local `static` is a one-time affair, it would be hard, if not impossible, to implement a general purpose synchronization mechanism on top of it, since every time you needed a synchronization point you would need to be initializing a *different* local `static` object.

Though they can be used in place of `call_once` in some circumstances, they can't be used as a general replacement for that, since a given `once_flag` object may be used from many places.