# call_once over local object's static initialization

Tags: c++, concurrency, static-initialization

I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490024/stdcall-once-when-should-it-be-used) question on when to use `call_once` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11) regarding thread safety of static initialization. It appears that if a local callable is statically initialized, it serves pretty much the same purpose. What nuances/design considerations should be factored in while choosing one over the other? Here's the specific use case that I'm having where we just want to log something once ([full compiling example](https://onlinegdb.com/UeQvse_XR)).

```
void fooCallOnceVersion() {
    static std::once_flag once;
    std::call_once(once, []() {
        std::printf("Foo call once\n");
    });
}


void fooStaticVersion() {
    static auto printLog = []() {
        return std::printf("Foo static version\n");
    }();
}
```

Comment: I like to express intent and `call_once` clearly calls out your intent.  a static variable initialized with an immediately invoked lambada takes more brain power to process and requires more background knowledge of the language to know what is going on.  That said, if it becomes a performance problem then that's a different story and a comment can be used instead.

Comment: you had to invent a value that is stored in `printLog` only to have a value that is stored statically. That can be considered a hack. At least to a reader it might be not obvious what the relevance of the value of `printLog` would be. `std::once_flag` on the other hand comes with plenty of documentation a reader of the code hopefully has access to

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai If there's no objective difference, that should be an answer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat removed my comment. Actually OP is asking what are the aspect to be considered (so that then they can make up their opinions) but they arent asking for opinions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `fooStaticVersion` you had to invent a value to be stored. This can be considered a hack while `std::once_flag` is properly documented. In your limited example, I am not aware of important differences other than that.

However, the `std::once_flag` can be stored elsewhere and allows multiple different calls to `std::call_once`. For example:

```
class foo {
     std::once_flag flag;
     void bar1(auto&& f) { std::call_once(flag,f); }
     void bar2(auto&& f) { std::call_once(flag,f); }
}
```

You cannot easily simluate the same with a `static` variable, because it would be the same for all instances.