# How to force eager-evaluation of templated read-only singleton function?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, templates, singleton, static-initialization

My codebase contains this very simple templated function that gets called from a lot of different places:

```
// Returns a read-only reference to a default-constructed
// object of the specified type
template <typename T> const T & GetDefaultObjectForType()
{
   static const T _defaultObject{};
   return _defaultObject;
}
```

This function is useful in templated code, since it allows the templated code to access a default-constructed object of the type it is templated on, without having to construct one for that purpose.

It works nicely, but the problem I ran into today is that [helgrind](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html) is telling me there is a race condition when I have multiple threads that call this function; that is because g++'s underlying implementation of the function apparently looks something more like this (pseudocode):

```
template <typename T> const T & GetDefaultObjectForType()
{
   static char _defaultObject[sizeof(T)];
   static std::atomic<bool> _isConstructed = false;
   if (_isConstructed == false)
   {
      _isConstructed = true;
      new (_defaultObject) T();  // demand-construct the object!
   }
   return reinterpret_cast<const T &>(_defaultObject);
}
```

... so because of the above, `helgrind` tells me that thread A's call to `GetDefaultObjectForType()` has written to the object (i.e. to demand-construct it) while thread B's code immediately after its call to `GetDefaultObjectForType()` has read from the object, and therefore there is a race condition.

I'm not sure if this is a real, will-bite-me-in-the-butt-someday race condition or just a false-positive caused by helgrind being too sensitive, but in either case, my question is the same:  **Is there some technique I can use to force the construction of the object to happen at (or near) the top-of-main, i.e. before any threads have been spawned, so that the singleton-object can be truly read-only as far as all the threads that call this function are concerned?**

Obviously I could manually call `GetDefaultObjectForType<EveryTypeIUse>()` at the top of `main()`, but  that would be a real maintenance hassle since I use so many different types of object that I'd be likely to forget to include some of the types (and it would force my `main.cpp` to have to `#include` a lot of header files that I'd prefer it not have to include).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is local static variable initialization thread-safe in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11)

Comment: @dewaffled possibly, but if so it raises the question of why helgrind reports a race there.  I wonder if my version of g++ is buggy, or if helgrind is reporting a false positive, or ?

Comment: You can look at how your function is compiled: https://godbolt.org/z/5T8vG8feP
It appears that there is thread syncronization here, done by __cxa_guard_acquire

Comment: Thread-safe static initialization is *required* by the C++ standard in this specific use-case and this is a very common use (e.g. Meyers' singleton), so it would be very surprising if it is a GCC bug. Maybe Helgrind can report false positif. This is not so rare with such tools (especially for static variable actually). Or maybe there is a bug in Helgrind so it does not consider this case.

Comment: I will require a citation of the pseudocode.  You are asserting a bug in gcc without any evidence I can see, other than helgrind complaining.  It is far more likely you do have a race condition in your actual code and helgrind has no bug, or helgrind has a bug.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont "I wonder if" is hardly an assertion, but you're right, a way to reproduce the fault would useful.  I've posted a .zip file containing a trivial example program, a Makefile to compile and run it, and the output I get from `helgrind` and `objdump` when I reproduce the fault, here:  https://public.msli.com/lcs/jaf/helgrind_test.zip  (FWIW I'm compiling with g++ 10.3.0 on an Ubuntu Linux VM, and testing with both valgrind 3.16.1 and the latest valgrind from git, aka valgrind-3.22.0-GIT)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I am asking about "that is because g++'s underlying implementation of the function apparently looks something more like this" - that isn't "I wonder if", but an assertion.  What basis do you have for the produced code "looking like" that?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont my basis for thinking that the static variable is initialized on the first call to the function is the report supplied to me by helgrind indicating that `GetDefaultObjectForType()` does a write to the `_defaultObject`, the first time it is called, and that in doing so it causes a race-condition.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner "and that in doing so it causes a race-condition" - and your belief it causes a race-condition is based off a single tool generating a diagnostic message?  I'm trying to figure out if you have an actual basis for your belief in that pseudo code other than helgrind.

Comment: I'm really not interested in whatever this pointless argument is about.  I'm interested in understanding why I'm getting the report from helgrind, and if there is any way to force a static variable to be initialized at process-start rather than the first time the function is called.  If you can shed any light on those issues, I welcome it; OTOH if you're just here to sea-lion me over what you've decided I believe, then I'm going to ignore you.